# Memory consumption of wpfgfx_v0400.dll

Tags: c#, wpf, memory, graphic, memory-consumption

I developed in c#. After a period which I used WindowsForms, I switch to WPF. After a time of developing I realized that my application needs more time to reduce the memory consumption after running a high process. With WinForms I had no problem with it. So I analyzed it with a memory profiler and I found that the wpfgfx_v0400.dll reserved much memory and after this it not reduced. So the question is what is the function of this library. I know that is a native WPf library and in context of graphic rendering but in which specially controls of wpf or object would be called this library?

Answer (score 3):

As a quick fix you can use this method to clear memory leak

```
  public class MemoryManagement
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Clear un wanted memory
        /// </summary>
        public static void FlushMemory()
        {
            try
            {
                GC.Collect();
                GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
                if (Environment.OSVersion.Platform == PlatformID.Win32NT)
                {
                    SetProcessWorkingSetSize(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle, -1, -1);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// set process working size
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="process">Gets process</param>
        /// <param name="minimumWorkingSetSize">Gets minimum working size</param>
        /// <param name="maximumWorkingSetSize">Gets maximum working size</param>
        /// <returns>Returns value</returns>
        [DllImportAttribute("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetProcessWorkingSetSize", ExactSpelling = true, CharSet =
          CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern int SetProcessWorkingSetSize(IntPtr process, int minimumWorkingSetSize, int maximumWorkingSetSize);
    }
```

Add this class to your application and call FlushMemory method where you met memory leak.

Comment: Wow it works great. What kind of dangerous aspects can happen when i used very of in short time distances?

Comment: If it worked ..please mark it as answer :-). You can have a search on SetProcessWorkingSetSize

Comment: When i read it the only thing happen with the function is to save it to disc. After a time of analyzing i see the that the problem is not the memory  in general my own code. I use a third party control (wpf control in core using c+++) when i work with it the memory  consumption grows up and when i dispose the control the memory consumption is not falling down. So question is if the function is really a good way because it can happen that the function would be calling very often.

Comment: I have using this function on regular intervals.I have not met any type of errors yet.